# Javascript, пролистывание элемента вбок

Tags: javascript

Есть длинная-длинная строка, заключенная в `div` с `overflow-x: scroll;`. Как сделать кнопку, при нажатии на которую содержимое строки будет пролистываться вбок на н-ное кол-во пикселей?

Мне не нужен готовый ответ, достаточно намека/подсказки :)

Comment: Element.scrollLeft. Тут можно почитать: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollLeft

Comment: Да, шикарно, это оно. Спасибо большое, я нагуглить не смог:)

Comment: @lonDen cделайте ваш коментарий конкретным ответом, чтобы было проще потом найти ответ ищущим =) Спасибо!